# Python/Pandas For Loop Time Series

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am working with panel time-series data and am struggling with creating a fast for loop, to sum up, the past 50 numbers at the current i. The data is like 600k rows, and it starts to churn around 30k. Is there a way to use pandas or Numpy to do the same at a fraction of the time?

The change column is of type float, with 4 decimals.

```
Index     Change
0         0.0410
1         0.0000
2         0.1201
...     ... 
74327     0.0000
74328     0.0231
74329     0.0109
74330     0.0462
```

```
SEQ_LEN = 50
for i in range(SEQ_LEN, len(df)):
    df.at[i, 'Change_Sum'] = sum(df['Change'][i-SEQ_LEN:i])
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Can you share a small part of your dataframe in the text form?

Comment: Just did =)! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I tried this with 600k rows and the average time was
20.9 ms ± 1.35 ms

This will return a series with the rolling sum for the last 50 Change in the df:

```
 df['Change'].rolling(50).sum()
```

you can add it to a new column like so:

```
df['change50'] = df['Change'].rolling(50).sum()
```

Comment: Works even better! Thank you! Just a quick one, if I wish to do rolling forward how would I approach that?

Comment: I would sort the df in the reverse order then apply the rolling sum.  One way to do that is: df['change50f'] = df.iloc[::-1]['Change'].rolling(50).sum()

Comment: Yeah, I had a similar idea, figured you can use a shift(50), and then apply the rolling. Thanks again!

Comment: I also tried shirt(50) first, but that didn't work on my first try so I did this.  I'm sure there are several ways to accomplish the same task :)

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**: This solution cannot compete with `.rolling()`. Plus, if a `.groupby()` case, just do a `df.groupby("group")["Change"].rolling(50).sum()` and then reset index. Therefore please accept the other answer.

Explicit `for` loop can be avoided by translating your recursive partial sum into the difference of cumulative sum (`cumsum`). The formula:

```
Sum[x-50:x] = Sum[:x] - Sum[:x-50] = Cumsum[x] - Cumsum[x-50]
```

### Code

For showcase purpose, I have shorten `len(df["Change"])` to 10 and `SEQ_LEN` to 5. A million records completed almost immediately in this way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# data
SEQ_LEN = 5
np.random.seed(111)  # reproducibility
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "Change": np.random.normal(0, 1, 10)  # a million rows
    }
)

# step 1. Do cumsum
df["Change_Cumsum"] = df["Change"].cumsum()

# Step 2. calculate diff of cumsum: Sum[x-50:x] = Sum[:x] - Sum[:x-50]
df["Change_Sum"] = np.nan  # or zero as you wish
df.loc[SEQ_LEN:, "Change_Sum"] = df["Change_Cumsum"].values[SEQ_LEN:] - df["Change_Cumsum"].values[:(-SEQ_LEN)]
# add idx=SEQ_LEN-1
df.at[SEQ_LEN-1, "Change_Sum"] = df.at[SEQ_LEN-1, "Change_Cumsum"]
```

### Output

```
df
Out[30]: 
     Change  Change_Cumsum  Change_Sum
0 -1.133838      -1.133838         NaN
1  0.384319      -0.749519         NaN
2  1.496554       0.747035         NaN
3 -0.355382       0.391652         NaN
4 -0.787534      -0.395881   -0.395881
5 -0.459439      -0.855320    0.278518
6 -0.059169      -0.914489   -0.164970
7 -0.354174      -1.268662   -2.015697
8 -0.735523      -2.004185   -2.395838
9 -1.183940      -3.188125   -2.792244
```

Comment: Bruh, you are amazing!

Comment: Thanks. I have finished experimenting and found the other answer is indeed superior and also generalizable. So please just go that way and forget this.